# Eclipse Run Application Configuration in IntelliJIDEA

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, intellij-idea, run-configuration

I've tomcat instance with some ear deployed and run it via Eclipse Run Configuration (Java Application configuration) in order to have a possibility to debug my code as it corresponds to the ear deployed on a Tomcat instance. I would want to have a possibility to debug the same application via IDEA, however, have no idea how to do it, my Eclipse Run Configuration is as follows:

**Main tab:**

a) Project - empty
b) Main Class - org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap

**Arguments tab:**

a) Program arguments - start
b) VM Arguments:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=128M  
    -Xmx800M 
    -Dcatalina.home="C:/Dumb/Dumb/Dumb-2.9.0/apache-tomee-webprofile-1.0.0/" 
    -Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:/Dumb/Dumb/Dumb-2.9.0/apache-tomee-webprofile-1.0.0/endorsed" 
    -Dcatalina.base="C:/Dumb/Dumb/Dumb-2.9.0/apache-tomee-webprofile-1.0.0/" 
    -Djava.io.tmpdir="C:/Dumb/Dumb/Dumb-2.9.0/apache-tomee-webprofile-1.0.0/temp" 
    -Dopencrx.CRX.jdbc.password=manager99111 
    -Dopencrx.CRX.jdbc.userName=sa111
    -Dopencrx.CRX.jdbc.url="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://127.0.0.1:9001/DB" 
    -Dopencrx.CRX.jdbc.driverName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
    -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.openmdx.kernel.url.protocol
    -Dorg.openmdx.persistence.jdbc.useLikeForOidMatching=false
    -Dorg.opencrx.maildir="C:/Dumb/Dumb/Dumb-2.9.0/apache-tomee-webprofile-1.0.0/maildir"
```

c) Working directory - C:/Dumb/Dumb/Dumb-2.9.0/apache-tomee-webprofile-1.0.0/

JRE tab - current JRE path

**Classpath tab**

a) User entries libs - C:/Dumb/Dumb/Dumb-2.9.0/apache-tomee-webprofile-1.0.0/lib - all libs from here and a couple custom libs

b) User entries projects - all projects from a workspace in order to debug

I wonder if its possible to create such a configuration with IDEA, I tried to create simple "Application" configuration, however, it allowed only to define classpath which corresponds to one of the projects currently imported to the workspace, but I cannot define it just as in **Classpath tab**

I would really appreciate any help,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a "Server" run/debug configuration (specifically a "Tomcat Server" run/debug configuration) rather then an "Application" run/debug configuration. I recommend you take a look at the following IntelliJ IDEA help pages:

1. [Migrating From Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA: Working with Application Servers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/eclipse.html#ApplicationServers)
2. [Working with Application Servers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/working-with-application-servers.html)
3. [Working with Server Run/Debug Configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/working-with-server-run-debug-configurations.html)